# Explain why the result from query on mysql looks like grouped data

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Can anybody please explain why the result from sql query on mysql looks like grouped data if its where clause was contain or operator?

i hope the following example will help you to understand my question:
lets assume we have table called mytable with two columns (col1,col2) contains the following data:

```
Col1    Col2
1         A
2         A
3         B
4         B
5         A
6         A
7         B
8         B
```

and if we applied the following query

```
Select * from mytabl1 where Col2 = 'A' or Col2 = 'B'
```

I expected the result to be like the following order (original order):

```
Col1    Col2
1         A
2         A
3         B
4         B
5         A
6         A
7         B
8         B
```

but what i got is the following:

```
Col1    Col2
1         A
2         A
5         A
6         A
3         B
4         B
7         B
8         B
```

the result looks like grouped by Col2, can i have good explanation for this behavior? how can i got the result like what i expected without using order by? because it will cause performance issue on huge data (millions) as i experienced before.

Comment: Simple select doesn't define any specific ordering. You have to use ORDER BY

Comment: Question is not on whether to use order by or not. OP wants some explanation on the observed behaviour.

Comment: The **only** (really: the *only*) way to ensure a certain order is to use `ORDER BY`. There is absolutely no alternative.

Comment: It seems that a select with multiple conditions gets split up. What I mean by this is that the select statement gets split up and both result sets are concatenated. Not sure this is the cause, gonna look for some documentation on it, quite interesting actually.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Well, that is well explained every here and there. Is there also any citation in MySQL documentation or somewhere else as '*conditional outputs are sorted*' or something like that, though not used an `order by` clause.

Comment: @Ravinder: conditional outputs are **not** sorted. The DBMS is free to choose *any* order it thinks is most efficient. Any "sorting" you might think you see is the result of the order the data was retrieved based on the execution plan. Changing the conditions might change the query plan and thus might change the physical output of the result.

Comment: @user3664760: :) You can accept [*above comment by a_horse_with_no_name*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23806357/explain-why-the-result-from-query-on-mysql-looks-like-grouped-data#comment36620511_23806357) as answer.

Comment: guys really thank you for your suggestions, but my point was if there is something could be help in displaying the result in order that i'm asking for instead of using the order by, because order by will take long time on huge data (10 millions) as i mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ORDER BY column` to sort rows.

example:

```
 SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE column1 = args OR column1 = otherargs
 ORDER BY column1 ASC
```

Comment: Question is not on whether to use order by or not. OP wants some explanation on the observed behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the entire table and remove the rows you don't want (if Col1 wasn't ordered) :

```
SELECT * FROM Mytable
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE (col2 <> 'A') AND (col2 <> 'B');
```

Comment: Not sure it will be faster

Comment: There is no `MINUS` in MySQL (or `EXCEPT` which would be the ANSI SQL operator for Oracle's `MINUS`)

Comment: oops, yes sorry. Maybe with a EXCEPT therefore ?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `except` either.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching a select query result without using a  `order by` clause doesn't guarantees any order for the queried results no matter how the data are initially stored in the Database.
The fact that you data is sort as:

```
Col1    Col2
1         A
2         A
3         B
4         B
5         A
6         A
7         B
8         B
```

Doesn't mean that if you use a simpe query

```
Select * fromSelect * from mytabl1
```

you get that order. Instead everytime you run the above query you will get a new (random) order, unless you specify a specific `order by` clause